# input in timed while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to allow the user to input a command in a timed while loop (0.1 seconds) it pauses at the input and doesn't get to the `time.sleep()` until the user enters something. For example:

```
while True:
    [something happens]

    userInput = input("Type something")

    if userInput = "foo":
        [another thing happens]

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I want the loop to run normally if there is no user input and process the user input if there is without pausing the entire loop.

Comment: I believe that's the point of `input`? Wait until the user enters something, no?

Comment: That's exactly what input is supposed to do. So no, there's no way to prevent input from doing this.

Comment: How should that work from the user's perspective? The user has less than 0.1s to enter something?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the input function requires it to wait until the user types something.